# Problem in adding Markers on google map from Django

Tags: jquery, django, google-maps

I am facing problem in showing markers on a google map
generated

http://psjinx.pastebin.com/TWcUP4kc

Answer (score 3):

Where are you initializing `i` in that code? I see lots of `i = i + 1`, but nothing that sets the initial value of `i`.